# Highcharts set x-axis categories

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am drawing my graph,

```
Data.chart.series[0].remove();
Data.chart.xAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({ text: xAxisTitle});
//Data.chart.xAxis[0].categories = xAxisCategories;
Data.chart.addSeries({
  name: yAxisTitle,
  data: formattedData,
  pointInterval: pointInterval
});
Data.chart.redraw();
```

I simply can't see anything in the documentation for changing the xAxis categories, is this possible? I couldn't see anything 4 changing the title, but managed to get a snippet online, I really need to avoid destroying & recreating the graph.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this with the `setCategories` method found on the Axis object. See the reference documentation for axis here: http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#axis-object

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4tuvC/

Comment: @eolsson you may need to update the highchart js links in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4tuvC/358/

Answer (score 2):

Since [Highcharts 5.0.0](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v5.0.0) you can use the [update()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update) function to update the chart options after render time:

```
Data.chart.xAxis[0].update({categories: xAxisCategories});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
Data.chart.xAxis["categories"] = ['a','b','c']
```